# observableArray sent as parameter to a contoller function is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to pass the data in the FeatureList (observableArray) to the SaveMappings function in the TreeController.  I have binded a button to the sendItems function.  I put a breakpoint at the var data=p2fData line to see what I received.  p2fData is null.

I changed the controller to public JsonResult SaveMappings(List p2fData).  In this case p2f data shows that there is 1 element, but then its null too.

```
var Feature = function (featId) {
    var self = this;
    self.featId = featId;    
    self.parameters = ko.observableArray();    
}

var ParameterToFeatureListViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var newFeature = new Feature("Feature XYZ");
    newFeature.parameters.push("1");
    newFeature.parameters.push("2");
    self.FeatureList = ko.observableArray([newFeature]);
    self.sendItems = function() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/Tree/SaveMappings',
           data: ko.toJSON(self.FeatureList),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {
               alert(response);
           },
           error: function (request, status, error) {
               alert(request.statusText);
           }
        });
    }
}

var vm = new ParameterToFeatureListViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);

public class TreeController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(){...}
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveMappings(string p2fData)
    {
        var data = p2fData;
        return Json(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't you have some real C# types in SaveMappings as a parameter? Why do you want to get all the data as JSON in a string? But if you want to have the JSON try with `data: JSON.stringify({ p2fData: ko.toJSON(self.FeatureList)}),`

Comment: After I do JSON.stringify I do get the data from the FeaturedList.  I thought ko.toJSON did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look @ [how to pass knockoutjs view model into a mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527309/how-to-pass-knockoutjs-view-model-into-a-mvc-controller/15533321#15533321)
... May be it helps..